# accessing methods and variables in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

Am working in console applications with visual studio in c# language.am new to this and am having silly doubts..
Am using a method with parameters as

```
public void display(int rank)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rank is:" +rank);                
        }
```

Now I want to assign this value to a variable and have to display.i write the method as

```
public void get(int rank)
        {
            string a;
            a = rank;
            Console.WriteLine("rank is:" +a  );                
        }
```

but am getting the error while accessing this through main function creating objects.Where am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what error you get, but from what i can see, you're trying to assign a string to an int (`a = rank`). Convert it to a string before assigning:

```
a = rank.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ToString` on `rank`:

`rank` is integer. You cannot assign int to string.

```
public void get(int rank)
{
    string a;
    a = rank.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("rank is:" + a);
}
```